# Question about function set_dont_touch_network

Tags: timing, synthesis, timing-analysis, sdc

I was trying to debug a script written for synthesis using Synopsys primetime.

Can someone explain me what is the function of `set_dont_touch_network`?

I have these 2 statements:

1. `set_dont_touch_network [get_ports scan_enable*]`
2. `set_dont_touch_network [get_ports resetb_i]`

What's is the difference between adding an asterix at the end of a signal or not? Can someone explain?

Comment: I'm not well versed in scripting languages... but my first thought was: the first is a pointer, the second is a variable

Comment: Hi @AdamHead I found out that the '*' is used as an expention operator- like for Example- if 3 variables: scan_enable1,scan_enable2,scan_enable3 are to referenced then the above used scan_enable* can be used to commonly reference all the variables.i am still searching for the fuctionality of the directive: set_dont_touch_network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command is used to prevent a clock network from being modified or replaced during optimization. It is Design Compiler command which is used during RTL synthesis.

```
set_dont_touch_network [get_ports scan_enable*]
```

it tells the DC to get all `scan_enable*` ports and also all the cells & nets that are also connected with these ports and then set `dont_touch` attribute on them. This attribute prevents those cells & ports from being modified during optimization. This is useful when you have an optimized network and you don't want the tool to modify the network during optimization.

There is another command `set_dont_touch` which sets `dont_touch` attribute only to the cells, ports & pins specified, not the elements connected in the fanout of them.

the asterisk (*) is actually one of the wild-cards used in various shell environments. it means to match any string or characters. like scan_enable_001, scan_enable_002 etc. [Here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3264) are more wild-cards used in TCL shell.